# Store Displayed UITableView Cell in NSString if Displayed for 2 Seconds

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with many cells in it. I want to track which cells are scrolled over and store an associated ID in NSUserDefaults.

This all works extremely well, but now I would like to add a timer that prevents the ID from being appended to the string unless it has been displayed on the screen for a full two seconds or more.

Here is the line where I append each new scrolled ID to the NSString:

```
NSString *scrolledIdPre = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@-", locationId];
```

Here is my full method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    NSDictionary *item;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
        item = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[filteredListItems 
        objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }else {
        item = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[listItems 
        objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
        reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    NSString *locationId  = [item objectForKey:@"location_id"];

    NSString *scrolledIdPre = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@-", locationId];

    [scrolledIds appendString:scrolledIdPre];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:scrolledIds forKey:@"impressions"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    return cell;
}
```

Any ideas would be wonderful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dispatch with delay and the check if cell is still visible

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
*)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    NSDictionary *item;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
        item = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[filteredListItems 
        objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }else {
        item = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[listItems 
        objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
        reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        // nil means that cell is no longer visible so it didn't meet the requirement for 2s displaying
        if ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] == nil) {
            return;
        }

        NSString *locationId  = [item objectForKey:@"location_id"];

        NSString *scrolledIdPre = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@-", locationId];

        [scrolledIds appendString:scrolledIdPre];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:scrolledIds forKey:@"impressions"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    });

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting an error at the 'if ([self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] == NO)' line. The error says "property tableView not found" any ideas how to fix?

Comment: I updated my answer, just remove self. from tableview, it is a param in method. Please accept answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks, i had tried that, but now i get a different error that says "implicit conversion of int to UITableViewCell is disallowed with ARC". ANy other suggestions? Thanks again!!

Comment: got it, replace NO with nil. nil means that cell is not present for given index

Comment: Woohoo you totally rock!! Thank you!